# Como identificar se um XML está com o caracter BOM?

Tags: java, xml

Estou com o seguinte problema em relação a codificação do XML:

```
Erro: Byte inválido 2 da sequência UTF-8 do byte 3.
```

Esse erro ocorre ao tentar canonizar um XML.

Não sei exatamente o que pode ser o erro, imagino que seja devido a String possuir o caracter BOM, sendo assim, alguém saberia me dizer se existe alguma função ou biblioteca em java para identificar se o XML está com o caracter BOM? Ou alguma função que remove o BOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca da apache [BomInpustStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) que ela faz esse trabalho para você, eu tive esse problema, e posso te afirmar com segurança, que utilizando essa biblioteca fica mais fácil para você. Uma dica pois eu também manipulei `XML`, você deve pegar o conteúdo com vetor de `bytes`, verificar com a API sugerida, e depois transnformar a `String` no `charset UTF-8`, só assim você não ira perder a acentuação gráfica.

Trecho para transnformar o source em inputStream

```
String source = FileUtil.takeOffBOM(IOUtils.toInputStream(attachment.getValue()));
```

Método para tirar o BOM

```
public static String takeOffBOM(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream);
    return IOUtils.toString(bomInputStream, "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adaptei a classe abaixo do artigo encontrado no link: [Removing BOM character from a String in Java](http://dev-faqs.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/removing-bom-character-from-string-in.html)

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class BOM {
private String bomString = "";
private final static String ISO_ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";
private final static String UTF8_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
private final static int UTF8_BOM_LENGTH = 3;

public void BOM(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    this.bomString = text;
}

public String removeBOM() {
    final byte[] bytes = this.bomString.getBytes(ISO_ENCODING);
    if (isUTF8(bytes)) {
        return SkippedBomString(bytes);
    } else {
        return this.bomString;
    } 
}

private String getSkippedBomString(final byte[] bytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int length = bytes.length - UTF8_BOM_LENGTH;
    byte[] barray = new byte[length];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, UTF8_BOM_LENGTH, barray, 0, barray.length);
    return new String(barray, ISO_ENCODING);
}


private boolean isUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    if ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) == 0xEF &&
        (bytes[1] & 0xFF) == 0xBB &&
        (bytes[2] & 0xFF) == 0xBF) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}